# How to mask bands of an image based on values of one of the bands using numpy and gdal

Tags: python, gdal, image, numpy, masking

I have a raster with two bands, and I want to mask both bands to get data where band "yod" has a value of 2011 and export a new tif file with the same two bands masked.
The following script does not work correctly since the mask is not applied to the output raster.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

# Read a file
dataset = gdal.Open('test.tif')

# read raster bands into numpy array
yod = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
mag = dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()

# create a mask based on a specific band
mask = np.where(yod == 2011, True, False)

# Apply masks for all bands
yod_masked = np.ma.masked_array(yod, mask=mask)
mag_masked = np.ma.masked_array(mag, mask=mask)

# Create a new raster for masked bands
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_path = 'output_masked_file.tif'
output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize, 2, gdal.GDT_Float32)
output_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())

# Write the masked bands to the output raster file
output_dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(yod_masked)
output_dataset.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(mag_masked)

# Save and close the output dataset
output_dataset.FlushCache()
output_dataset = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simplified version of your solution by masking in fewer steps (assuming the band order is always the same):

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

# Open the raster file
dataset = gdal.Open('test.tif')

# Read the raster bands into a numpy array
array_to_mask = dataset.ReadAsArray().astype(np.int16)

# Define the value threshold for masking
threshold = 2011  # Change this value to your desired threshold

# Do the masking in two steps
array_to_mask[0][array_to_mask[0] != threshold] = 0
array_to_mask[1][array_to_mask[0] != threshold] = 0

# Create a new raster file for the masked bands
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_path = 'array_to_mask.tif'
output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize, 2, gdal.GDT_Int16)

# Set the projection and geotransform
output_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())

# Write the masked bands to the output raster file
for i, masked_band in enumerate(array_to_mask):
    output_band = output_dataset.GetRasterBand(i + 1)
    output_band.WriteArray(masked_band)
    output_band.SetNoDataValue(0)

# Save and close the output dataset
output_dataset = None
```

Comment: Thanks, just one small change to make it work: in line 27, masked_array_data should be changed to array_to_mask.

Comment: @Isa, fixed. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

# Open the raster file
dataset = gdal.Open('test.tif')

# Read the raster bands into numpy arrays
yod = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.int16)
mag = dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray().astype(np.int16)

# Define the value threshold for masking
threshold = 2011  # Change this value to your desired threshold

# Create a mask based on the specified band
mask = np.where(yod != threshold, True, False)

# Apply the mask to all bands
yod_masked = np.ma.masked_array(yod, mask=mask)
mag_masked = np.ma.masked_array(mag, mask=mask)

# Create a new masked array with both bands
masked_array = np.ma.array([yod_masked, mag_masked])

# Convert the masked array to a regular numpy array
masked_array_data = masked_array.filled(fill_value=0)

# Create a new raster file for the masked bands
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_path = 'output_masked_file.tif'
output_dataset = driver.Create(output_path, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterYSize, 2, gdal.GDT_Int16)

# Set the projection and geotransform
output_dataset.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
output_dataset.SetGeoTransform(dataset.GetGeoTransform())

# Write the masked bands to the output raster file
for i, masked_band in enumerate(masked_array_data):
    output_band = output_dataset.GetRasterBand(i + 1)
    output_band.WriteArray(masked_band)
    output_band.SetNoDataValue(0)

# Save and close the output dataset
output_dataset.FlushCache()
output_dataset = None
```